# How to replace string with value and the occurance number?

Tags: regular-expression

I have a beamer(LaTeX) file containing many `\begin{frame}` lines. I want to debug the code to viewing the output of its. The pdf output shows frame number. When I try to change a specific numbered frame in source I have to give more time to find out that frame as there is no fame numbering in source code.

So, I want to give frame number as comment in each `\begin{frame}` as `\begin{frame}%frame_no` when it is not commented yet.

But, I don't want to write this each time when I add a frame and calculate the number. I want to make this autonomous such that when I press `:w` or any user command it add the frame number.

Sample file -

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{Input:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicoutput{\textbf{Output:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinitialization{\textbf{Initialize:}}
\algnewcommand\Input{\item[\algorithmicinput]}%
\algnewcommand\Output{\item[\algorithmicoutput]}%
\algnewcommand\Initialize{\item[\algorithmicinitialization]}%


\logo{%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{Image/DUlogo}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2cm-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm,keepaspectratio]{Image/GNR.png}%
}
\begin{document}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation With  Elastic Service Scaling in Cloud Radio Access Network}
  \author[alhelal \& Jobayed Ullah]{
  \parbox{2.5cm}{
\centering Md.Al-Helal\\Roll:SH-51}\hspace{1cm}
\parbox{2.5cm}{
{\centering Jobayed Ullah\\Roll:EK-107}}
}
\institute[CSEDU]{Computer Science \& Engineering\\CSEDU}
\date{February 25, 2018}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
  \title{Cross-Layer  Resource  Allocation With  Elastic Service Scaling in Cloud Radio Access Network}
  \author{Jianhua Tang\\ Wee Pen Tay\\ Tony Q. S. Quek}
\institute{IEEE Transactions on Wireless Communications, vol 14, no. 9}
\date{September 2015}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}
  \author{alhelal \& Jobayed Ullah}
\institute{CSEDU}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to proceed without needing to define an helper function.

The idea is to fill a list and to inject the list size with `:s\=`.

```
:let counter=[]
:%s/\\begin{frame}\zs\(%\d\+\)\=/\='%'.len(add(counter, 42))
```

Or as a command in a `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex/count-frames.vim` ftplugin file:

```
command! -b -range=% -nargs=0 NumberFrames 
    \ :let g:counter=[]|:<line1>,<line2>s/\\begin{frame}.\{-}\zs\(%frame_\d\+\|$\)/\='%frame_'.len(add(g:counter, 42))
```

Which will work on the whole buffer by default, or only on a given range that can be defined explicitly  (`:12,42NumberFrames`) or with a visual selection (`'<,'>NumberRanges`)

Comment: would you edit your answer so that it put `framenumber` at end of the line for `\begin{frame}{\relax}`?

Comment: add `frame_number` instead of just `number` so that I can find a frame easily by searching.

Comment: `:12,42NumberFrames` works but `:%sNumberFrames` doesn't work.

Comment: This is normal. To delete or to yank, we don't type `%sd` or `%sy`. We type `%d` or `%y`. `%s` is for `%substitute`. The range for the whole file is `%`, not `%s`. [`:h :range`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3arange)

Comment: yes you are right. I know `s` for substitute, but as I use this all times, I forgot that `NumberFrames` is not substitution. Thank you. Please,Consider my 1st 2 comments.

Comment: I already had changed my post. I didn't know whether you'd be notified. Now I know this is not automatic.

Comment: `42` means what?

Comment: It's the [Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)). :)
In this case this is a dummy value I use to fill the list every time an occurrence of `\begin{frame}` is found. This way, I can count them, and I have an expression that alters a _counter_ and that returns the value of that _counter_. In C, I'd have simply used `++counter`, alas this is not possible in vim scripts.

Comment: that means it works for `1` instead of `42` also.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to to it with e.g. a custom command. Something like this should work:

```
function NumberFrame(match)
    let g:number+=1
    return a:match.'%'.g:number
endfunction

:com! NumberFrame :let g:number=0|:%s#\(\\begin{frame}\)\(%\d\+\)\?#\=NumberFrame(submatch(1))#
```

That uses a custom command `:NumberFrame`, that first initializes the counter, followed by a `:s` command that looks for `\begin{frame}` followed by an optional comment, takes the input to a function that increments the counter and returns the input followed by your comment. So in your Latex document simply call `:NumberFrame`.

You can put that definition into `~/.vim/vimrc` (or whatever vimrc file you are using) or you can put that into `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` to make that command filetype specific (e.g. it will only be available in tex documents). Make sure you have a line `:filetype plugin on` in your .vimrc to enable filetype specific plugins. In that case you should probably put a `:let b:undo_ftplugin=':delcommand NumberFrame'` to delete the command when another filetype is loaded. See the help at [:h undo_ftplugin](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#undo_ftplugin)

You can get more fancy about it (e.g. add some more error conditions, refine your regular expression, recount on `BufWritePre` autocommands, etc). But as such it is a simple solution that shows how to do the main thing.

See the help at [:h sub-replace-expression](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression)

Comment: Please, mention where(e.g.,`.vimrc`) I put those and what is the command to execute this function?

Comment: I have updated the questino.

Comment: both the function `NumberFrame` and `:com! ...` line in `tex.vim`? I put `NumberFrame` in `tex.vim` and execute `com! ...` in command mode inside vim, that doesn't work.

Comment: Put both inside tex.vim that should be loaded by vim whenever it detects the filetype tex. See `:h ftplugins`. If it still does not work, you might want to ask another question.

Comment: The command should be defined buffer-wise with `command -b`. I'm not sure we really need to undefine the command if the end-user wants to change the current filetype to something else for files  ending in `.tex` in a simple (undistributed) case. And in that case, it should be `let b:undo_ftplugin .=` -- several ftplugin files can coexist.